# local variable 'output_file' referenced before, this code worked a few weeks ago, now it doesnt work how is that possible?

Tags: python, file-io

This thing is hard to post code and context inside of.
    #This is a menu driven multiplication game. i am attemtping to save the high 
    #score in a file named multiplication_game.txt...

```
def single_player():
    in_file = open('multiplication_game.txt', 'r')
    highest_times_selection = int(in_file.readline())
    print('\n____now lets see how u do on the times tables____')
    correct = 0
    missed = 0


times_selection = int(input(
'\nPlease enter a times time table integer to practice: '))

#This simple generates the multiplation questions and checks for right or 
#wrong.

for number in range(0,11):
    print(times_selection, 'x' , number, '=')
    user_answer=int(input('answer: '))
    correct_answer = times_selection * number

if user_answer == correct_answer:
    correct+=1
else:
    missed+=1

#This is where if its a perfect score and a high times table than the 
#previous saved score it should be opened and the new score saved in the 
#text document.  

if missed == 0 and times_selection > highest_times_selection :
    output_file = open('multiplication_game.txt', 'w')
    name = input('You have the highest Score!!\n enter your name: ')
    output_file.write(str(times_selection)+ '\n')
    output_file.write(name + '\n')
else:
    print('you missed ', missed, 'and got', correct,'correct\n')
    output_file.close()
```

Comment: Could you re-post the code with correct indentation in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define `output_file = None` before any assignment of it.

Tip: before your last `if-else` condition.

Comment: i tried this , python will respond with name none is not defined. i did get it working though thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, so I don't want to give you the answer but rather lead you to it.

Take a look at your if/else for your high score table, and walk through your code twice, taking a different branch (different part of the if/else) each time you reach this spot. Write down the variable names on paper as you define them, starting over with a new sheet of paper each time you walk through. If you access a variable, check it off on your list. If you try to access a variable that's not on your list, it's the same as python saying `local variable referenced before assignment` -- you're trying to access it before you've defined it.

Hope this helps, both in figuring out your problem and learning how to debug in the future.

Comment: No i am learning this on my own just a game i came up with. So I wanted to keep my object variables seperate so i know when im reading data or writing data. I cahnged the input_file variable to output_file and it works now. But i am confused because while i am making a reference to output_file i am also making a assignment to it as well, why does it say no asignnment? "open('textfile', 'w')" is the assignment correct? thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes the assignment is correct, the problem is _when_ you access it. The only way it will reach the definition of output_file is if you've already happened to get in the high score table, i.e. reached your first if/else branch (which is possible in your code). Trying to close output_file in the `else` if you haven't already opened it creates two problems: 1) you haven't defined the variable yet so it can't find the file to close, and 2) even if you defined `output_file = None` outside the if/else, it still can't close the file because there isn't one at that variable.

Comment: Your options here would be to open **and** close the file immediately after you're done writing it, or open it before reaching the if/else and closing it after.